# Read filebeat configration from Http URL?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat

Is there any way to read filebeat configuration from an URL?

I want to start filebeat in windows from command line like this

" filebeat.exe --path.config='http://XXXXXX/filebeat.yml' "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This option does not seem to be supported in the doc, but you could have your script grab the config before starting filebeat.

Comment: Thanks @Alain. Is there any way that we could listen on changes on that config file, and reload?